# Boldy Theme - Tweak PHP for 2nd Logo?

Tags: logo

Running WordPress 3.1 with the free Boldy theme from Site5.

Here is a working version of my website: http://www.dekhoforum.com

I want to achieve something like this screenshot:
[image]

i.e. Have a 2nd logo above the social media icons.

EDIT
*- Screenshot shows moving an existing image to the new location.

This is misleading, and I actually need a new placeholder for an image, and not to move the existing logo (which is the right image), as this will not be consistent on the other pages such as the [blog](http://www.dekhoforum.com/?category_name=blog).
- In short, its a marketing requirement to get this logo at the top of each page, across the entire site.*

One option I did ponder, was somehow trying to add another social media icon, but link it to my main company website.

I have tweaked PHP in the past on previous themes, but always had a little guidance from you wonderful lot.

Was wondering if anyone could advise? I have been snooping in the header.php, but I imagine I will need to write a new line in somewhere?

Any help would be great.

Comment: How can I tweak my Question to get an answer? Perhaps I need to include a sample of the header PHP code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This can easily be accomplished with CSS.

Sometimes it's better to use CSS to modify your theme.  I use the [Web Kit developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to make live edits in the browser until it looks right then save it back to CSS.

Edit the following lines in style.css.

```
/* line 201  pulled down the icons to make room for the 2nd logo */
#topSocial {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 150px;
}

/* line 80  add relative positioning to the wrapper div to allow the logo to be positioned absolute */
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    position: relative;
}

/* line 85 made the header a little taller to make room for the 2nd logo*/
#header {
    height: 220px;
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/bk_header.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}


/* line 312 moved the logo in place using position absolute */
#blurb img {
    border:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px; 
    right: 15px; 
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

The result:

[image]

---

***Edit after question was clarified that an additional logo was needed***

To add an additional logo open your header.php file and find the lines that look like this:

***Edit***

#### The 2nd logo code shown below should go at line 78 in your header.php file

[image]

```
<!-- END TOP SEARCH -->
<!-- BEGIN TOP SOCIAL LINKS -->
```

Between those two line add the basic XHTML to display a linked image:

```
<!-- END TOP SEARCH -->
<!-- BEGIN 2ND LOGO -->
<div id="new-logo">
<a href="http://link_you_want_image_to_point_to"><img src="http://url_of_image" width="xx" height="xx" /></a>
</div>
<!-- END 2ND LOGO -->
<!-- BEGIN TOP SOCIAL LINKS -->
```

Use the exact same CSS I gave you above except change

```
#blurb img {
     border:none;
     position:absolute;
     top: 90px;
     right: 15px;
     margin-top: 5px;
}
```

to:

```
#new-logo img {
         border:none;
         position:absolute;
         top: 90px;
         right: 15px;
         margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: This is amazing = Really impressed, and will take a more in depth look at editing CSS live in the browser.  

However... My screenshot is a little misleading.
If I applied your fix, the logo would vanish on other pages like the blog - http://www.dekhoforum.com/?category_name=blog
As the 'blurb' section, only appears on this home page.

Comment: Therefore, I need to find a way to actually add a 2nd image.  See edits to original Q

Comment: What information do you need to provide an answer?  
Don't get me wrong, ur answer is great and does provide a solution, but I should have worded my Q better.  (Revised)

Comment: I gave you the exact code to make it work.  Did you read my edited answer?  The code I gave you above should be inserted at line 78 in header.php.